# Xpath to select the the particular instance if it returns more than one

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is the XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable')]"))
```

the above XPath returns three elements on that page, and I want to select the third element and I'm framing the XPath below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable')][3]"))
```

Pass `[3]` in the end of the XPath.

But I received the below exception.

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable')][3]"}
```

Let me know how can I select a particular instance if the XPath returns more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that xpath working without selenium in that page?

You could use findelement**s** and take the third element

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable')]")).get(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pure XPath solution:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable')])[3]"))
```